# $g(x) = 3x^2-6x$. What is $g(x + h)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, notation

I am really confused on what this question is asking. h isn't defined anywhere in the problem, and I am not sure how to plug in $g(x)$ if there is an unidentified variable also in the equation. Do i distribute.. or something else? Not sure! Please help

Comment: I only can see $g(x+h)=3(x+h)^2-6(x+h)=3(x+h)(x+h-2)$

Comment: @BrandonFinley It's the same idea as if it had asked "*what is $g(5)\,$?*" - you replace $x$ with $5$ and calculate. In this question, you replace $x$ with $x+h$.

Comment: Welcome to math.se, Brandon.  Please keep your previous title: it is more informative and will help others with similar questions find yours. To indicate that the problem is solved, please select one of the answers by clicking on the green tick-mark.

Answer (score 2):

Just plug $x+h$ instead of $x$: $$g\left( x+h \right)=3{ \left( x+h \right)  }^{ 2 }-6\left( x+h \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

One has
$$
g(x+h)=3(x+h)^2-6(x+h)=3 x^2-6x+6 h x-6 h+3 h^2=g(x)+6 h x-6 h+3 h^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I only can see $$g(x+h)=3(x+h)2−6(x+h)=3(x+h)(x+h−2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$g(x+h)=3(x+h)^2−6(x+h)=3(x^2+2hx+h^2)-6x-6h=3x^2+6hx+3h^2-6x-6h$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a function is an operation that processes an input, and returns an output. In this case both the input and output are real numbers, but the function isn't a number; it's a rule that relates the numbers from the domain, with the numbers in the range. What this means, is that you can choose any variable to define the function. All of the following definitions mean the same thing:

$$g(x) = x^2-6x$$
$$g(t) = t^2-6t$$
$$g(r) = r^2-6r$$
$$g(\gamma) = \gamma^2-6\gamma$$
$$g(3) = 3^2-6\cdot 3$$

So to simplify the problem, try defining $g$ with a different variable name (e.g. $r$)
$$g(r) = r^2-6r$$

and just substitute $r=x$ to find $g(x)$.
$$g(x) = x^2 - 6x$$
Then substitute $r = x+h$ to find $g(x+h)$
$$g(x+h) = (x+h)^2-6(x+h)$$

And just to reiterate, a function isn't a number; it's what you do to a number.